# Enable log entries for all users in django application

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

**Is there a way to add/enable log entries for all crud action in all models by any user?**

```
from django.contrib.admin.models import LogEntry

#this seems to exempt from logentry actions by non-admin users
return LogEntry.objects.all()
```

Answer (score 0):

### DRF-TRACKING APP

If you're working with the Django rest framework, [drf-tracking](https://drf-tracking.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) gives a straight solution.